# Defining unique certain event space S in application of total probability law in problems of two boxes

Tags: probability

My question is on the provided solution of the example 2-14 from the Probability book by 'Papoulis and Pillai':
First, we have two mutually exclusive events $W$ and $B$ that forms a partition of $S$. i.e. $W$ = {transferred ball is white}, $B$ = {transferred ball is black}. 
So far so good. Definition of $S$ clear to me.

My confusion starts when we apply total probability law to event $A$ (that includes different box) 
where $A$ = {white ball is drawn from the second box}.

What I cannot visualize is how the event A belong to the same $S$ as $W$ and $B$. $W$ and $B$ only include box $1$, whereas A includes only box $2$.

In other words, what I want to clearly draw or write is the definition of $S$ here.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

Although the book solution still confuses me, this is how I understood the problem.

Since, one (either white or black) ball from first box, and one (either white or black) ball from second box exhausts all possible outcomes, I define certain space S as following:
 {ww, wb, bw, bb}; where for example wb represents white ball drawn from first box and black ball drawn from second box and so on.

Its trivial to note that outcomes of S form partition of S.

Then event of interest A = {ww, bw} consists of two outcomes from S.

With this clear formulation of the problem in terms of S and A, now, our task is to find p(A). For this, we use the fact that four outcomes of S form a partition. So, we can write p(A) = p(ww) + p(bw).

Next, we write p(ww) = p(w|w)p(w) and similarly p(bw) = p(w|b)p(b).

Now, its only left to put the numbers:

p(w) = $\frac{a}{a+b}$.
p(w|w) = $\frac{c+1}{c+d+1}$.
p(b) = $\frac{b}{a+b}$.
p(w|w) = $\frac{c}{c+d+1}$.

and we get the same answer as derived in the book.